# How to handle background uploads with Alamofire 5?

Tags: alamofire, background-process, urlsession, nsurlsessionconfiguration

There is a chance that background uploads work with some adaption of the alamofire api and URLSession whit this code:

```
Alamofire.upload(
                multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
                    multipartFormData.append(imageData, withName: "photo[image]", fileName: filename, mimeType: "image/jpg")
            },
                usingThreshold: UInt64(0), // force alamofire to always write to file no matter how small the payload is
                to: "http://", // if we give it a real url sometimes alamofire will attempt the first upload. I don't want to let it get to our servers but it fails if I feed it ""
                method: .post,
                headers: headers,
                encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
                    switch encodingResult {
                    case .success(let alamofireUploadTask, _, let url):
                        alamofireUploadTask.suspend()
                        defer { alamofireUploadTask.cancel() }
                        if let alamofireUploadFileUrl = url {
                            var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://yourserver.com/photoUploadEndpoint")!)
                            request.httpMethod = "POST"
                            for (key, value) in alamofireUploadTask.request!.allHTTPHeaderFields! { // transfer headers from the request made by alamofire
                                request.addValue(value, forHTTPHeaderField: key)
                            }
                            // we want to own the multipart file to avoid alamofire deleting it when we tell it to cancel its task
                            // so copy file on alamofireUploadFileUrl to a file you control
                            // dispatch the request to the background session
                            // don't forget to delete the file when you're done uploading
                        } else {
                            // alamofire failed to encode the request file for some reason
                        }
                    case .failure:
                        // alamofire failed to encode the request file for some reason
                    }
            }
            )
```

Unfortunately this wont work with Alamofire 5, is there a way to adapt this?

Comment: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/2721  here is the detail discussion

Comment: I am saving data on dist ...in my case, it's a video ... and when the user comeback from the background or after terminating the app I restart uploading with `Alamofire` ... and delete the video from storage when is got successful...

Answer (score 1):

Alamofire 5 doesn't support background `URLSessionConfiguration`s, but the code you posted is just a multipart upload, which is still supported just fine.

Your various hackery around the upload should be reevaluated for the new version of Alamofire. It really doesn't make any sense.

Alamofire does work with background tasks, which can give you time to finish uploads. You can read more [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/85066).

Comment: This is not my code, I am just looking for something I can use with Alamofire 5 and  background uploads, so that I dont have to replicate the multipart logic all over again.

Comment: I've added a link to background task documentation which you can use to keep uploads alive for a limited time in the background. There is no way to use Alamofire with background sessions. Alternatively, you can use Alamofire's multipart encoding and upload with a raw `URLSession`.

Comment: what do you mean? is there an example code to do this raw URLSession?

Comment: @JonShier 
Is this valid url that you provided ?
Seems to be related to TLS client authentication.
Can you please update URL to correct one ?

Comment: @Jim You're right, fixed!